# Unable to change "on host maintenance" option for an instance template on GCP

Tags: virtual-machines, google-compute-engine, autoscaling, multiple-instances, gcp

I've been using instance templates for Instance Groups, and I never had to go to "Advanced Options" because everything was working as expected. But today, while creating a new instance group with a template it started throwing the following error:

```
" Operation type [compute.instanceGroupManagers.insert] failed with message "Instances with guest accelerators do not support live migration." "
```

which upon searching, I got to know that was `'on host maintenance'` option was set to `'Migrate'`, then I tried to change that option to `'Terminate'` as it was set by-default for previously created templates, but it didn't allow me to change it for some reason, and the reason it was mentioning that I have to choose `'Standard'` option for `'VM provisioning model'`, which was already set. Any help would be appreciated.[GCP console image while creating instance template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsF0O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by setting up the VM in google console and display the corresponding code, copied it to a command line, changed `--maintenance-policy=MIGRATE` to `--maintenance-policy=TERMINATE`, and created the VM from the command line.

Comment: The above answer works perfectly fine. I also found another way of doing that without leaving console, turns out GCP console doesn't allow you change `on host maintenance` option after you select GPU machine for the template, but you can change that option if no GPU is selected yet, so what one can do is to first select a CPU machine and set the `on host maintenance` option to `Terminate` , then we can go back and select GPU machine, the option will stay there set to `Terminate`, and there won't be any issue in using this template in a managed instance group.

Comment: There was a temporary issue with GCP console at that moment, but now it's fine and one can select `Terminate` option.